# Can "work experience" be plural?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, syntax

When I have worked for multiple jobs, and I use "work experience," is it plural?

For example, my education and work experience make me a great candidate for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry for **experience** in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/experience) contains two definitions:

> [ U ]
> (the process of getting) knowledge or skill from doing, seeing, or feeling things

> [ C ]
> something that happens to you that affects how you feel:

The first one is the kind of experience that relates to work. There is a [U] next to this entry: this indicates that is uncountable. Uncountable nouns like **sugar** and **peace** do not have a plural.

The second meaning relates to things that happen to you. There is a [C] next to it: this indicates that it is countable, so you can have many experiences of this kind.

Because you are using the word relating to work experience, it is uncountable, so you should not use a plural.